# change project 2013 task parent programmatically

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2013

How can I change task parent in Project Server 2013 via client object model?
I can achieve this in Project 2013 Professional.
In DraftTask class "Parent" property is read only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't.
A solution would be to clone your actual task and set its new parent task in the TaskCreationInformation class ("ParentId" property).